# How to Make Button Tag Only Show Image Inside of it

Tags: html, css, image, button, submit-button

I have the following code for a submit button on my website:

```
<button name="searchterm" type="submit" id="searchterm"><img src="images/ICON_Go.jpg"></button>
```

and the following CSS:

```
#searchterm {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:auto;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vneSL/)

and this is how it appears on the live website:

[image]

I would just like it to be the green `go` image. I do not want the button graphic surrounding the image. How can I do this?

Thank you for any help. All help is appreciated.

Comment: is there any reason to calling image using `src` attribute?
instead of calling the image as background?

Comment: Yes, my personal preference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to remove the background color and the border:

```
#searchterm {
    border:0;
    background:transparent.
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gx6tW/)

Comment: Glad to help! If it solved it, could you mark it as the answer to help people looking in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will fit what you need?

```
<button name="searchterm" type="submit" id="searchterm"></button> 

    button {
    appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gojXZ.jpg');
    background-size:40px 34px;
    background-position: 18px 5px;
    padding:22px 38px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/K9CVj/)

Answer (score 1):

you need to reset the default styles for a button: `button{ border:0; padding:0; outline:0; background:transparent;}` and add to your image: `{display:block; }`

Answer (score 1):

I would think this will be a better approach to calling the image using `background-image` CSS property.

```
#searchterm {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

/--small alert code which proves this is actual button-/

```
function myFunction()
{
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
```

/-HTML code---/

```
<button name="searchterm"  type="submit" id="searchterm"  onclick="myFunction()"></button>
```

this way this will work as actual button. check the Demo. http://jsbin.com/malorefa/1/